# Tableau calculated field distinct sum of metric base on selected dimensions

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

I have this table imported to tableau and face a challenge in aggregating it correctly in the calculated field. I want to sum base_count but don't want to sum the duplicate base_count.

I only want to **sum distinct base_count by date and problem**

[image]

I want the chart result to look like this, which in sql is

```
select date, problem, sum(count), sum(distinct base_count) as base_count
from table
group by date,problem
```

[image]

I tried exclude,include, fixed level of detail expressions, I am a beginner in tableau. Anyone better idea what functions to use to count the distinct **base_count** **by date by problem dimensions**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer through my teammate in tableau by using **FIXED**:

First created a calculated field name **base** with the following:

```
{FIXED [url], [date], [problem],[base_count]: max([base_count])}
```

Then do another calculated field:

```
Sum([count])/Sum([base])
```